# Bootstrap : As a beginner, which bootstrap version should one learn and use?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

While trying Bootstrap I found that some classes in v3 and v4 are not the same.
For example, for a specific thing(in some cases) the class name in v3 and v4 are different. 
**The main reason for the confusion to choose between v3 and v4 is that most tutorials teach v3 but I'm worried that v4 would replace v3(idk, just an assumption that new things replaces old) and v3 code wont work with v4!**
Thank you for checking out my noobish question, I'd really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It cost nothing to learn both actually. I currently do bootstrap 3 only, but I know upgrading to bootstrap 4 would be stress free. Most WYSIWYG editors supports v3 out-of-the-box. I will say you should learn v3 then v4 when u r comfortable with v3. What matters is your experience.

Comment: That was my whole point in asking, whether to learn both or just to learn v4. Now that I have realized that switching to v4 is easy i'll learn v3! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You're definitely right, new versions are meant to replace old ones.
So learning on the latest version definitely makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Tutorials only exist for v3 because v4 is not even released yet (currently it's [in beta](https://blog.getbootstrap.com/2017/08/10/bootstrap-4-beta/)). But it will be released, it will replace v3 and therefore tutorials will surely appear on the web for v4 too.

But why would you need a third-party tutorial, when there is (already) the **[official documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/)** with categorized samples, explanations and example code for **everything**? :)

If I were you, I'd learn v4. (Unless you have to maintain v3 code.)

(I'm moving from v3 to v4 these days, and v4 seems much better to me. It has more breakpoints, more helper classes, rethinked and improved components.)